# How to get the before and after of selected text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I am trying to implement **Bold** and *Italic* in Jquery with stars and underscores (like in whatsapp). By using [Madapaja's Selection Library](https://github.com/madapaja/jquery.selection), I can add stars or underscores, but I cannot figure out how to remove stars or underscores if exists before and after the selected text. I know there are duplicate questions but I want to achieve this by using the library since it has the cross-browser support.

I am adding stars like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#boldButton').click(function () {

        var selection = $("#inputQuestion").selection();

        if (selection.trim()) {//not empty or not whitespace
            $('#inputQuestion')
            .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'before' })
            .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'after' });
        }
    });
});
```

to this html:

```
<button id="boldButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><b>B</b></button>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="inputQuestion"></textarea>
```

You can examine the [wiki](https://github.com/madapaja/jquery.selection/wiki/API) and the [source code](https://github.com/madapaja/jquery.selection/blob/master/src/jquery.selection.js)

Any help or any other methods will be appreciated!

**Update**:
With dpren's answer, I achieved like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#boldButton').click(function () {

        var selection = $("#inputQuestion").selection();
        var selectedPos = $("#inputQuestion").selection('getPos');

        if (selection.trim()) {//not empty or not whitespace
            var before = $('#inputQuestion')
                .selection('setPos', { start: selectedPos.start - 1, end: selectedPos.start })
                .selection();

            var after = $('#inputQuestion')
                .selection('setPos', { start: selectedPos.end, end: selectedPos.end + 1 })
                .selection();

            if (before == '*' && after == '*') { //already bold -> remove stars
                var before = $('#inputQuestion')
                    .selection('setPos', { start: selectedPos.start - 1, end: selectedPos.start })
                    .selection();

                $('#inputQuestion').selection('replace', { text: '' });

                var after = $('#inputSoru') //since we remove 'before', positions will decrese by one
                    .selection('setPos', { start: selectedPos.end-1, end: selectedPos.end })
                    .selection();

                $('#inputSoru').selection('replace', { text: ''});

            } else { // not bold -> make it bold
                $('#inputQuestion') //get back to user's selection
                .selection('setPos', { start: selectedPos.start, end: selectedPos.end })
                .selection();

                $('#inputSoru')
                    .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'before' })
                    .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'after' });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However, I think this code has repititions. Is there a way to achive this by editing selection library?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to remove anything. If you have * text * and someone selects <text> and clicks "bold" again, you will have ** text ** - doesn't look like a problem. The output parser you use to replace the stars into html tags will replace the most outer stars with a bold tag. So finally you will have * text * in bold letters, which is perfect.

Comment: It is not perfect when you display stars to end user. Look to the stackoverflow's design, when you double click bold button, it removes the stars.

Comment: @ninbit FYI - what you're referring to is called "markdown", it comes in different flavors, and the way you go about reading it is called "parsing". Try googling "js markdown parsing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a simpler solution to your overall parsing problem, but as to your immediate question you can use `getPos` and `setPos` to expand your selection after the insert operation.

```
var position = $('#inputQuestion')
    .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'before' })
    .selection('insert', { text: '*', mode: 'after' })
    .selection('getPos');

var newSelection = $('#inputQuestion')
    .selection('setPos', {start: position.start - 1, end: position.end + 1})
    .selection();
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n0bpuxL7/2/)

Comment: Actually, I want to check the selection's before and after, whether it has a star both ends. I mean, if it is bold already, then remove stars and un-bold it